# Calculating the current through coil with a flyback diode using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, physics, simulation, event-detection

I plan to simulate the current through a coil with flyback (or freewheel) diode for an arbitrary voltage signal (square or PWM modulated signal is possible).

You can find the circuit diagram over here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode#/media/File:Flyback_Diode.svg

[image]

My idea to use `NDSolve` worked out very well for my first step calculating the coil without the diode. I used:

```
res = 
  NDSolveValue[{l*i'[t] + r*i[t] == u[t], i[0] == 0},i, {t, timeStart, timeEnd}]
```

Where `u[t]` is a function that is not necessarily continuous (pulse width manipulation signal is possible), `l` stands for inductivity, `r` for Ohms resistance and `i[t]` for the current I am looking for.

My problems occur when I want to take the flyback diode into account. My first very simple approaches to use add a function like:

```
uFB[i_: 0, u_: 0] := If[i > 0 && u > 0, -1, 0];
```

It failed, producing the message:

> NDSolveValue::smpf: Failure to project onto the discontinuity surface when computing Filippov continuation at time 0.`.

The message disappears when I use the option `Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}`, but then the results I produce don't fit the physical behavior of the part (for example: setting the resistance to 0 and giving different values for the amount of `uFB` does not change the solution)

I also tried to find a solution using `WhenEvent`, but this was also not successful.

I am interested in any suggestions that might solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a numerically more stable solution:
It was provided by xzczd. He came up with the idea to add a small deviation term within the formula for `vdiode`. With this it becomes a differential equation, that is easier to handle for *Mathematica*. The new introduced term is so small due to the factor `eps`, that it does not effect the result. I checked the result with an experiment and it is working. It is much more stable then the first approach.

```
timeStart = 0;
timeEnd = 15;
r = 0.1;
l = 1;
uPWM = 1;
PWMFreq = 1;
PulseDuration = 10;
uPart[t_, PulseDuration_] := 
Piecewise[{{Sin[π*t/PulseDuration], 0 <= t <= PulseDuration}}, 0]
u[t_, PWMFreq_, PulseDuration_] := 
If[Mod[t, 1/PWMFreq] > uPart[t, PulseDuration], 0, uPWM]
Plot[u[t, PWMFreq, PulseDuration], {t, timeStart, timeEnd}, 
  Exclusions -> None, ImageSize -> Large]
With[{eps = 10^-3}, 
res = NDSolveValue[{l i'[t] == 
 u[t, PWMFreq, PulseDuration] - 
  r i[t] - (i[t] - 10^-14 Exp[vdiode[t]/(25/1000)]), 
eps vdiode'[t] + vdiode[t] + l i'[t] + r i[t] == 0, 
vdiode[0] == 0, i[0] == -1/2*10^-14}, {i, vdiode}, {t, timeStart, timeEnd}]]
Plot[Evaluate[Through[res[t]]], {t, timeStart, timeEnd}, PlotLegends -> {"i", "vdiode"}]
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution :

```
u[t_]:=Piecewise[{{0,t<1},{10 (t-1),t<1.1},{1,True}}]
rsw[t_]:=Piecewise[{{1,t<2},{1+ 90 (t-2),t<2.1},{10,True}}]
l=0.3;
r=1;
res=NDSolveValue[{
l i'[t]==u[t]-r i[t] - (i[t]- 10^-14 Exp[vdiode[t]/0.025]) rsw[t],
vdiode[t] + l i'[t] + r i[t]==0,
vdiode[0]==0,
i[0]==-1/2 10^-14
},
{i,vdiode},
{t,0,3}
]

Plot[Evaluate[Join[{u[t],rsw[t]/10},Through[res[t]]]],{t,0,3},
     PlotLegends-> {"u","switch\nresistance","i","vdiode"}]
```

[image]

u[t] change from 0 Volts to 1 Volt at t = 1 second.

I have made a lot of conservative and maybe useless choices :

- The switch is modelised by a resistor whose value change from 1 Ohm to 10 Ohm at t = 2 seconds.
- The diode is modelised by : idiode = Is Exp[q Vdiode/(k T)] (without the -1 after the Exp[...]))
- no discontinuities

Improvements and more explanations are coming tomorrow

Comment: Already thank you a lot for your answer. It looks very interesting and I will have a closer look at it today. I am very curious about the Improvements and the explanations.

Comment: Your approach is definitely working. I adapted it implementing my PWM signal but still facing sometimes two different errors, which are most likely due to numerical issues. The first one is:
 _NDSolveValue: Some of the functions have zero differential order, so the equations will be solved as a system of differential-algebraic equations._
while in other cases I get:
_NDSolveValue: Error test failure at t == 0.00004 unable to continue._
Maybe I have to find a way to tune my variables. If you are interested I can provide my source code

Comment: I have opened a chat room about my answer [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34754011#34754011)

Comment: @Tchibi The message about "zero differential order" is normal. This always happen when you have a equation without derivatives: NDSOlve use the DAE solver.  [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104846/5467)