# Chop intermediate results of NDSolve after each step

Tags: differential-equations, complex, machine-precision

Using `NDSolve` for a set of three ordinary differential equations, I ran into the problem that intermediate results quickly develop negligible imaginary parts. I get the error

> For the method IDA, only machine real code is available.
>   Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point
>   exceptions.

Unfortunately, the equations themselves are very long and I haven't yet been able to reproduce the issue in a simpler example, so I can't offer an MWE at this point. However, adding the option `StepMonitor :> Print[{t, var1[t], var2[t], var3[t]}]` to `NDSolve` gives

```
{-0.0001,0.020001,0.499998,-0.0000663528}
{-0.0002,0.0200019 +0. I,0.499997 +0. I,-0.0000663555+0. I}
```

So the iteration fails already in the second step. The imaginary part appears to be due to rounding errors. My question is, is it possible to apply `Chop` to all variables after each step? Or alternatively, is there a method other than IDA that is equipped to deal with complex numbers?

Comment: `NDSolve` can work with any numerical black box, not just with symbolic equations. You can use `f'[x] == fun[f[x], x]` inside NDSolve and have a separate definition `fun[fx_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := Chop[...]`.  This may not be this straightfoward if you have a differential algebraic equation though.

Comment: Would inserting `Re[]` in the appropriate places be feasible?

Comment: Without a specific example it's hard to give effective suggestions, but IDA method is for DAEs, so your system is a DAE system. (At least `NDSolve` thinks so.) A possible work-around is to modify the DAE system to an ODE system, [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136620/1871) is an example.

Comment: @J.M.That's the strange thing. I already did. All three ODE's are of the form `var'[t] == Re[func[var[t]]]`, yet the problem persists.